# How to upgrade paper_trail from 3.0 version to highest version to solve the serialized_attribute issue in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I am Using Rails 4.2 with Paper_trial gem version 3.0. I am getting the following deprecation error

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: `serialized_attributes` is deprecated without replacement, and will be removed in Rails 5.0.
```

So, as per this [link](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/416) I am trying to upgrade the Gem to highest i.e 6.0 version. But I am getting the following error

```
superclass mismatch for class Version (TypeError)
```

What are all the steps to upgrade the paper_trial from 3.0 version to 6.0 in Rails 4.2 ?

Comment: In that case you need to carefully read the changelog.md file and see for the deprecations/breaking changes in gem versions & progress along the gem levels & modify your code if it uses those methods..https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: The comment by @uDaY is good (and should probably be an answer, not a comment). 3.0 -> 6.0 is a big jump. Best to do it one version at a time and read the changelog carefully. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! @JaredBeck with your encouragement, I added it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're upgrading from v3.0 to v6.0, you need to carefully read the changelog.md file and see for the deprecations/breaking changes in gem versions & progress along the gem levels & modify your code if it uses those methods..

See the [CHANGELOG](http://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)